# Single field search multi fields auto fill using twitter typeahead.js v0.10.2

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, twitter, typeahead.js

I have a data set as like as `var links = [{ title : 'title1', link : 'link1', target : 'target1' }, { title : 'title2', link: 'link2', target: 'target2'}`

My HTML code as below :

```
<input type="text" name="title" class="title">
<input type="text" name="link" class="link">
<input type="text" name="target" class="target">
```

I can set autocomplete for each input field individually using [typehead.js (v0.10.2)](http://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/) using my `links` variables. But is it possible if I set autocomplete for class `.title` and when [`typehead:selected`](https://github.com/twitter/typeahead.js/blob/master/doc/jquery_typeahead.md#custom-events) event fired, then `.link` and `.target` input fields also complete with corresponding values.

Comment: See the answer here http://stackoverflow.com/a/21591540/203371 as this may do what you want.